# TLS 1.3 Http Library for Windows

Tags: library, c#, ssl, https

I have been looking for a http library with TLS 1.3 support that works on windows but haven't found. Implementing using native windows features seems impractical so far as well. I know chrome achieves this with boringssl and something else but the library alone is only useful as an openssl drop-in and not a full HTTP/TCP library.